# Can't find point instance

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, edit-mode, instances

I'm following [a tutorial](https://youtu.be/9RGEhDPRqgM) (4:57 time stamp) where the person gets point instances and in Blender 3.0 its gone.

How do I get the same effect in Blender 3.0 now that it has changed completely?

Answer (score 5):

Probably like this:

You will just use whatever you want instead of that **Cube** node
[image]

If you want to use object in your scene, like in tutorial:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much, you saved the day..  have a great one mate!